# CSS dropdown menu vertical

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a vertical dropdown menu but doesn't seem to work. It currently doesn't display any text, just a bar going across the top of the page. It is being pushed to be by by 115px for due to requirements. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<h1>Flags </h1>
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="flags.html#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
  <li><a href="flags.html#history">History</a></li>
  <li><a href="flags.html#national">National Flags</a></li>
  <li><a href="flags.html#international">International Maritime Signal Flags</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="flags.html#letters">Maritime Signals: Letters</a></li>
        <li><a href="flags.html#numbers">Maritime Signals: Numbers</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
nav {
    height:30px; 
    }

nav ul {
    background-color: #5d2c2c; 
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 115px;
    display: block;
}
    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

nav ul li {
    float: right;
    bottom: 115px;
    position: relative;
}
    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 5px 5px;
        color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;
        text-align:right;
    }
nav ul ul {
    background: #5d2c2c; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
        position: relative;
    }
```

Comment: You should try to pare this down to the bare minimum amount of HTML and CSS required to display your problem. Forget all the color and background styles, for instance. Also, try posting a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS needed a little work on 
Try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QMH32/) it'll work

This was missing:

```
nav ul li:nth-child(4) ul { display:none; }

nav ul li:nth-child(4):hover ul { display:block; color:red; }
```

and bottom was removed from this one

```
nav ul li {
  float: left;

  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link the other day, it's an step by step guide with full examples, check it out: http://www.adam-bray.com/blog/91/Easy+HTML+5+%26+CSS+3+Navigation+Menu/

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline." http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cocoa_beans/LLTKZ/) , a similar implementation

```
<nav>
    <ul>
     <li class="header">
            <a href="#">People</a>
        <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
    <li class="header">
            <a href="#">Animals</a>
        <ul class="content">
            <li><a href="#">Sub 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

nav > ul{}
nav > ul > li{float:left;margin:0 5px;background:#cc3333;}
.header li a{background:#eee;color:#cc3333;}
.header li a:hover{color:#fff;background:#cc3333;}
ul{padding:0;}
li{list-style-type:none;}
a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none;padding:5px;display:block;text-align:center;}
.content{
    display:none;
    }
.header:hover > .content{display:block;}
```